# How to delete parent static methods in extended class

Tags: php, laravel

Here is my model

```
<?php

namespace App\Models;

use Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model;

class Associate extends Model
{
   // some code       
}
```

In controller I use this model similar this

```
<?php

namespace App\Http\Controllers;

use App\Models\Associate;
use Illuminate\Http\Request;

class AssociatesController extends Controller
{
    protected $associate;

    public function __construct(Associate $associate)
    {
        $this->associate = $associate;
    }

    public function edit(Request $request, $id)
    {
        $associate = $this->associate->with('some-relation')->find($id);
        // other part of code
    }
}
```

When i wont to testing in controller `edit` method using `phpunit` I cant mock `with` method because it is static method of `Illuminate\Database\Eloquent\Model`.
**My question there is way to delete some method of parent class??**

Answer (score 0):

From Laravels [documentation](https://laravel.com/api/5.6/Illuminate/Database/Eloquent/Model.html)

```
static Builder|Model with(array|string $relations)
Being querying a model with eager loading.
```

From Php [docs](http://www.php.net/manual/en/language.oop5.late-static-bindings.php#101077)

```
<?php
class A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
    public static function test() {
        static::who(); // Here comes Late Static Bindings
    }
}

class B extends A {
    public static function who() {
        echo __CLASS__;
    }
}

B::test();
?>
```

The above example will output:

**B**

Comment: I wont to my extended class does not have **with** method. It is possible??

Comment: the controler class from which you are extending doesnt not have a private static with method,the model does,therefore if you are gonna try the late static binding you would do that in the Associate Model and you cant delete static methods

Comment: It is not possible static methods??

Comment: I have never done it,nor I have seen any example,however I would advise in this case you **dont** have to at all,you can create a custom function and save yourself ,its much easier and comfortable

Comment: I can change my code **$this->associate->with()**  to other for example **$this->associate->select('id', ...)->with()**  and can esly test it. But for me essential find way delete parent methods. I think it can helpfull for large amount of problems.